# Something with my Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, program-entry-point

Trying to make a helloworld app from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html but I cant run it! I'll did it step by step, but something is wrong, I cant run main(). Tool windows "Run" and "Debug" are inactive. 
https://pp.vk.me/c625817/v625817357/24acb/B8HcByLp7D8.jpg
Screenshot (cant post it)

Idea Community Edition 14.02, Win8 x64

Comment: What happens when you right click your class and click Run (Ctrl+Shift+F10)?

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c625817/v625817357/24b9f/OalIO4R6GIA.jpg

Comment: From that menu which pops out select option "Run Redactor". What happens then?

Comment: "Run" or "debug" - nothing happens.

Comment: If you press Alt+4 do yo see console output of your application?

Comment: No, i dont. Those windows are inactive. https://pp.vk.me/c625817/v625817357/24b97/UGN8WyzLz6s.jpg

Comment: Can you check whether you have JDK properly set up? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

Comment: Version 1.8, seems to be ok...

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/M4lQoE09f9k6R

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/D9olb0inf9kAD

Comment: Do you use shared or network disk for your project working directory?

Comment: Project was on my cloud storage, files basing somewhere on C:\users\.. . I created a new one on C:\ and still nothing happens =(

Comment: According to some other stack overflow post i found, intellij idea has problem when the project is on network disk. Did you create your new project from scratch or copied existing one including idea .iml files?

Comment: No, it was a new one from File-New project

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches and restart

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/JssnlMt7fAVeK

Comment: After a few minutes this updating is done, but still nothing happens after "run". In context menu now I have a "Run 'Redactor.main()' " string.

Comment: My problem was solved with help of Idea support (ty Andrey Dernov). Something was with internal http server, jre 8 and IPv6. After installing jre 7 and some more magic it works, but i still dont know what trouble it was.